# sscanf is failing in matching a string

Tags: c

I'm just doing a very simple sscanf and it's failing and I have no idea why (I'm a beginner in C).

I believe it should work and am going mad over this ...

Here's the code sample:

```
int rval; // return value
char* buf;
    
char* file = "/proc/stat";

long unsigned int intr=0, introld=0;

buf=file2buf(file);
if((rval=sscanf(buf, "intr %lu", &introld)) < 1) perror("ERROR");
printf("buffer: %s\nintrold: %lu\n", buf, introld);
free(buf);
```

And here's what it prints out:

> ERROR: Success
>
> buffer: cpu  1226442 3373 193292 19167181 57056 3 154 0 0 0
>
> cpu0 323691 790 47844 4778847 9693 0 62 0 0 0
>
> cpu1 290857 1430 42436 4804284 20607 0 25 0 0 0
>
> cpu2 326087 608 57761 4763973 10862 2 40 0 0 0
>
> cpu3 285805 544 45249 4820075 15893 0 25 0 0 0
>
> intr 48727278 36 26655 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 11277 0 0 3788861 0 0 0 70288 0 0 2 0 0 0 33 0 0 443731 0 25936 1429307 25 893 2807619
>
> introld: 0

Obviously the matching string (intr) is there. What obvious mistake am I making?

Comment: `sscanf(buf,` --> `sscanf(strstr(buf, "intr"),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your buffer.  It contains '`cpu ... blah blah`'.
For sscanf to work the buffer must start with `intr` only.

Or - as suggested in other comments - you must manicure the strings being passed in the `sscanf` function, so that you extract the string following `intr` and pass that to sscanf only.  (ie without the cpu + extra guff - AND without intr)  Try to simply pass the number (the string containing the number) to `sccanf` without forcing it to do characters matching too.

You can use `p=strstr(buf,"intr")` and then use `sscanf(p+5,"&lu"...)` ...the p+5 will skip the characters for 'intr '

Comment: It is the same (see C11, 6.7.2 par. 2).

Answer (score 3):

The [`scanf` family of functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) does not do general pattern matching, it tries to match the input *exactly* which means that the string you pass to `sscanf` have to *begin* with `"intr"` for it to be able to match.

You should consider reading line by line from the file and attempt to match using e.g. `strncmp` and then call `sscanf` on a matching line. Or possibly look up a regular expression library.